# When I change physical location of start menu folder in registry does the actual start menu folder on drive change also?

Tags: windows-8.1

Question #1:
When I change physical location of start menu folder in registry does the actual start menu folder location on the hard drive change also? I do not think the physical start menu location changes after changing the location in the registry. Am I right about this?

Before answering question #2, please note that there are two physical start menus on my HD:
One is in             c:\program data\microsoft\windows
and the other is in   C:\Users\jim\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu

Question #2:
1. I want to merge the two start menus into one
2. I want the location to be c:users\myusername\my documents\start menu

Any help on this, please?

Comment: The two start menus don't work like that. The"Program Data" one is the public location where "all users" shortcuts are created. The "Roaming" folder in your profile is for programs and shortcuts specific to your profile. It is a very bad idea to move either.

Comment: Thanks, Big Chris. What are your specific reasons that it is a bad idea, please?

Comment: It's unnecessary and causes confusion with public and individual entries. The "ProgramData" folder is hidden for a reason. Why do you need to merge them?

Answer (score 0):

This seems like an odd thing to do, but here is how I think it can be done. (I am assuming that **you are the only user on this computer**. This will mess things up for any other users.):

1. Open up an [administrator command prompt](http://pcsupport.about.com/od/windows-8/a/elevated-command-prompt-windows-8.htm). Leave this open. You will use it later.
2. Open up `regedit` and go to `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\User Shell Folders`. Change `Start Menu` to `%USERPROFILE%\My Documents\Start Menu`. (More info on this can be found [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc962621.aspx).)
3. Move the `C:\Users\jim\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu` folder to your `My Documents` folder.
4. Open up `C:\Program Data\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu` and drag the contents of this folder into `C:\Users\jim\My Documents\Start Menu`. If you get this dialog then choose "Yes" to merge all directories (also choose to overwrite files if prompted).

   [image: Dialog Window]
5. Remove `C:\Program Data\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu`. In the command prompt from step 1 type the following:

   ```
   mklink "C:\Program Data\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu" "C:\Users\jim\My Documents\Start Menu"
   ```

Step 4 will effectively merge the shared start menu into your user start menu. Step 5 sets up a [symbolic link](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/16226/complete-guide-to-symbolic-links-symlinks-on-windows-or-linux/) so that whenever a program tries to add an entry to the shared start menu, it will add it to your user's start menu instead. Note that this *might* cause duplicates to appear in your start menu. I have never tried this so I don't know how well it will work.

Comment: You might also be able to find the registry key for the shared start menu and change that to `C:\Users\jim\My Documents\Start Menu` instead of creating the symlink in step 5.